# SCONS building in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, scons, building

While building scons from `readme.scons.txt` from https://github.com/iotivity/iotivity in Ubuntu 13.0, I get

```
Linking out/linux/x86/release/resource/c_common/oic_malloc/test/malloctests extlibs/gtest/
gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
 extlibs/gtest/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
 extlibs/gtest/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete' 
extlibs/gtest/gtest-1.7.0/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific' 
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status scons: *** [out/linux/x86/release/resource/c_common/oic_malloc/test/malloctests] Error 1 scons: building terminated because of errors
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to properly format it - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit to add any details in order to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: Somebody forgot to append `'-pthread'` to the `CCFLAGS` and link it with `LIBS = ['pthread']`